# Is there a way to add a function on close of ng-multiselect-dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I am using the [ng-multiselect-dropdown](https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown) package in angular 5 for creating a multi-select dropdown. 
I want to do call a function on close or hide of the drop-down component.

like  this

```
closeDropdown : function(){
   console.log("dropdown close triggered");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation you can pass `closeDropDownOnSelection` value `true` to close the dropdown whenever the selection is done

[ng-multiselect dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown)

Incase of multiple selection you can call `(onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"`

for more information check this [Demo documentation](https://nileshpatel17.github.io/ng-multiselect-dropdown/)

Comment: closeDropDownOnSelection this one only works for single select not multiple. If you set this to true for multiple select it will close the drop-down on every time user select a option.

Comment: Edited check the new answer

Comment: Thing is there is a scenario here. This event will trigger every change which will increase the load. Thing is on close I want to check how many of them selected. If only one is there on the list then call a function. In this scenario, if I use your suggested solution every time I select this will check that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function within `(change)` event.

ex :

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
  (blur)="closeDropdown($event)"
>
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Comment: Change is not a possibility here. I have to do on close only. On select and deselect there are other functionality going on. Because if I use on (change) it will do call the function even if not required. I want to call this function on specific condition when it closes.

Comment: Use `blur` instead.

Comment: There Lib doesn't provide support for blur. I tried to call a function on blur but it doesn't trigger any event.

Comment: ng-multiselect-dropdown does not offer (blur). According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown use (onDropDownClose). But for me it triggers too often, not only when the user closes the box in the UI, but any time I click elsewhere in the form and when the component is loaded and other situations I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the bug identified by satira ( I couldn't comment due to low reputation), ie.
"When the component which has this multi-dropdown opens for the first time or you reload the page and click anywhere outside the dropdown, onDropDownClose() gets called." For me, it didn't happen after the first time. Anyway, i solved it by getting the id of any element on the screen(header, footer or any div) and used docuement.getElementById('element_id').click() on ngAfterViewInit.

`ngAfterViewInit() { document.getElementById('header').click(); }`

This made sure that no sideeffects take place on my app. I know this is a messy solution but since closeDropdown() of ng-multidropdown doesn't work, this was my only way out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently and found a solution that works for me using a combination of (ngModelChange) and (click). When using ng-multiselect-dropdown the other normal HTML Element triggers like (blur) and (change) don't work, but the (ngModelChange) does work. Only problem with that is it triggers when being initialized. But I added a boolean variable to the (click) trigger that does seem to work.

Note that this also works to cover the onSelect, onDeSelect, etc

component.ts:

```
...
dropDownSelect: boolean = false;
dropDownSelection: number;
...
saveFunction(event) {
  if(!this.dropDownSelect) return;
  ...
  this.dropDownSelect = false;
}
```

component.html:

```
...
<ng-multiselect-dropdown [data]="dataSource" [(ngModel)]="dropDownSelection" [settings]="dropDownSettings" (click)="dropDownSelect = true" (ngModelChange)="saveFunction($event)"></ng-multiselect-dropdown>
...
```

Comment: Had to come back and revise my answer. Apparently that solution doesn't work ONLY in the situation of when a user is focused in another field and then deletes one of the multi-select items. This does not trigger the (click) before the (ngModelChange). What I ended up doing was using an [ngModel] so that it was not modifiable from the front end, and then using the (ngModelChange)="saveFunction($event)" to detect if there were any changes between the $event and the original item. This seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

I tried @misterz's solution but it didn't work. However I modified it and it works perfectly.
The trick:
In addition to (onDropDownClose), listen to a click event;

```
 // this act as a differentiator between other calls(bug) and an intended call
 (click)="dropDownSelect = true".
```

In your component, declare your variable and use it like this:

```
dropDownSelect = false;

saveFunction($event) {
 if (this.dropDownSelect) {
        // close the opening to subsequent actions 
        this.dropDownSelect = false;
        // Perform action;
 };
}
```